# Reason for really slow 14.04 LTS performance

Tags: performance

Ubuntu newbie/ computer novice with a question on performance.
Downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from a purchased disk. The installation process went flawless. My problem is the OS is crawling (hovering the curser over an icon takes 10 seconds for the text to appear, clicking on an icon takes at least 30 seconds for the screen to appear). This computer is an older 32 bit Emachine running XP SP3. Specs:
Intel Celeron 2.70 ghz.
1.2G memory (original 256m that I expanded by adding 1G).
Graphics are Intel 845GX86/MMX/SSE2
80G hard drive that I partitioned (25G for Ubuntu, plus the swap partition).

I ran memory check and it came back fine (all 1.2G recognized). I defragged and ran disk check prior to the installation with no errors. I changed swappiness to 10 with no change to the performance. I ran the check for additional graphic drivers and received "no additional drivers found". 
I realize my old computer won't give optimum performance on the Unity desktop, but is this super-slow condition normal? Would I be better off with Xubuntu or an early Mint version OS?
I'm aware of the command "sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback" to change the DE but have not gone that route yet.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance for any comments or help.

Comment: your processor is very old. ram is also very less, consider buying ram to make 2gb or more. OR don't use unity, try KDE desktop or Other light weight distro like lubuntu or Elementary OS

Comment: Downloaded gnome-session-fallback and that made all the difference; my computer now rocks! I can't believe the difference in speed.

Answer (score 2):

You will be better of with a different flavor of Ubuntu. I am running Lubuntu on my old computer with low resources (also Intel celeron around the same specs).

For a full list of flavors:

http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours

Answer (score 1):

For something that old you should use something like lxle : Visit http://lxle.net/

You can try Lubuntu as well both are good alternatives to run on your pc

Comment: oh, I missed the second line, sorry for the dupe.

Comment: i think we answered at the exact same time so its ok =) check out LXLE friend ive been having a lot of good feedback when using it instead of Lubuntu

Answer (score 0):

your processor is very old. ram is also very less, consider buying ram to make 2gb or more. OR don't use unity, try KDE desktop or Other light weight distro like lubuntu or Elementary OS